# Where to create a header in Iconic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In a tutorial I am following about Iconic, I came across this line:

```
<ion-pane>headers and other things are here</ion-pane>
```

Since I can not find this line in my app, I don't know where to put my headers and tabs.Does any one have any suggestion?
This is my HTML script, with the content of both head and body sections:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <script data-ionic="inject">
    (function(w){var i=w.Ionic=w.Ionic||{};i.version='3.9.2';i.angular='5.0.3';i.staticDir='build/';})(window);
  </script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs//intro/tutorial/project-structure/ docs

Answer (score 0):

In pages folder. If you don' t have a pages folder you run this code in terminal `ionic generate page pageName` and go pages folder. [enter link description here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/)
will be useful to examine it.

Comment: You are welcome,  please click 'this answer is useful' (up arrow). Have a good day :)